# Ubuntu stops booting at 'Stopping network device security'

Tags: 14.04

I'm having issues with my ubuntu to boot. Worked fine yesterday but i think some updates has made my box to fail booting.

I remove the 'quiet' and 'splash' from grub cmdline to see what is happening when it tries to boot.

Everything seems to start/stop fine except when it reaches 'stopping configure network device security'. It just hangs there

the last few lines look like this:

- starting configure network device security  [ OK ]
- stopping configure network device           [ OK ]
- stopping configure network device security  [ OK ]

Also, it show's that GNOME Display Manager that it failed starting, not sure if that has something to do with it or not.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooooo... after a day searching i found the problem.

I don't know why or how but there was a bug in the gdm init script. I have no idea how it got there though.

The way i found it was by trying to restart it manually by doing `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart`

Then it said there was something wrong on a line and i removed it.

It does start now just not on boot. will look into that later, at least i can work now.